# Rails with Devise: user details not being updated in tests (but works in application)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise, minitest

My test for a new Rails app is failing for reasons I can't understand. The application itself works but the test doesn't - I can update a user profile with no issues.

The test is for updating the user profile details, which is controlled by the Devise `registrations_controller`. I have not over-ridden this part of the controller so the code there is vanilla.

Test code:

```rb
sign_in @admin
get user_path(@admin)
assert_response :success
assert_template 'users/show'
assert_select "p.user-name", text: @admin.name
assert_select "p.user-email", text: @admin.email
#Can edit own user profile
new_name="New name"
put user_registration_path, params: {user: {name: new_name, email: @admin.email, current_password: 'password123'}}
get user_path(@admin)
assert_select "p.user-name", text: new_name
```

Fixture:

```rb
admin:
  id: 11
  email: $LABEL@example.com
  name: $LABEL
  slug: $LABEL
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password123') %>
  admin: true
  organisation_id: 1
```

When I run the test, it produces an error at the final `assert_select` of
"`<New name> expected but was <admin>.. Expected 0 to be >= 1.`", showing that the record hasn't been updated.

Extensive use of `byebug` shows that the error is caused because the record isn't being updated within the Devise `update` controller, leading to it going down the `else` route at [line 57](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb). However, I can't see why this isn't working in the tests when I can update profiles in the application!

If I replace the `put ...` line with `@admin.update_columns(name: new_name)` then the test passes, so it definitely looks like something's wrong with my `put` command, which is odd because the same line works in a previous Rails application. (And I've tried `patch` with the same results, although the working form in the application uses `put` which is why I've stuck with that in the test.)

The working form code from the application (with HTML cruft stripped out):

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: registration_path(@user), html: { method: :put, id: 'edit-user-account' }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "Name", class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>

    <%= f.label :email %><br/>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email@example.com", class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>

    <%= f.label :current_password %>
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "current-password", class: "form-control form-control-lg" %>

    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Any advice gratefully received!

Ruby 2.6.3, Rails 5.2.3, Devise 4.6.2, minitest 5.11.3, rails-controller-testing 1.0.2

====Edit====

Given the comment chain below, I thought I should include my routes, so it's clear what the setup is.

```rb
new_user_session      GET        /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#new
user_session          POST       /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session  DELETE     /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                         devise/sessions#destroy
new_user_password     GET        /users/password/new(.:format)                                                                     devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password    GET        /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/passwords#edit
user_password         PATCH      /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#update
                      PUT        /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#update
                      POST       /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET     /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                           users/registrations#cancel
new_user_registration GET        /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                          users/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET       /users/edit(.:format)                                                                             users/registrations#edit
user_registration     PATCH      /users(.:format)                                                                                  users/registrations#update
                      PUT        /users(.:format)                                                                                  users/registrations#update
                      DELETE     /users(.:format)                                                                                  users/registrations#destroy
                      POST       /users(.:format)                                                                                  users/registrations#create
                      GET        /users/sign_up/:e/:cid/:token(.:format)                                                           users/registrations#create
organisation_tags     GET        /organisation/:organisation_id/tags(.:format)                                                     tags#index
                      POST       /organisation/:organisation_id/tags(.:format)                                                     tags#create
organisation_tag      DELETE     /organisation/:organisation_id/tags/:id(.:format)                                                 tags#destroy
organisation_dashboard_layouts GET /organisation/:organisation_id/dashboards(.:format)                                             dashboard_layouts#index
organisation_dashboard_layout GET  /organisation/:organisation_id/dashboards/:id(.:format)                                         dashboard_layouts#show
                      PATCH      /organisation/:organisation_id/dashboards/:id(.:format)                                           dashboard_layouts#update
                      PUT        /organisation/:organisation_id/dashboards/:id(.:format)                                           dashboard_layouts#update
organisation_remove_dashboard_tag DELETE     /organisation/:organisation_id/organisation/:organisation_id/dashboards/:id/tag/:tag_id(.:format) dashboard_layouts#remove_tag
organisation          GET        /organisation/:id(.:format)                                                                       organisations#show
user                  GET        /profiles/:id(.:format)                                                                           users#show
add_user_tag          PATCH      /profiles/:id(.:format)                                                                           users#add_user_tag
remove_user_tag       DELETE     /profiles/tag/:id(.:format)                                                                       users#remove_user_tag
profile_toggle_org_admin PATCH   /profiles/toggle_org_admin/:id(.:format)                                                          users#toggle_org_admin
invited_users         POST       /invited_users(.:format)                                                                          invited_users#create
resend_invitation_email POST     /invited_users/resend/:id(.:format)                                                               invited_users#resend_invitation_email
```

Comment: You were on the right track with your byebug work, you just needed to delve a litle deeper. Given that's it's going down the `else` statement in line 57 of Device's `registration_controller` I would follow that up by checking what's going on in line 50, specifically, are the two parameters of the `update_resource` method what you expected them to be. If either of them isn't right then that would take you further up the file with the debugger to check how they came out wrong, e.g. if the `resource` parameter is wrong, then you would dig into line 47.

Comment: If both of those parameters on line 50 seem right then you would have to step into the `update_resource` method to find out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this was, in the end, that the test database wasn't up to date. I dropped and recreated the test db (using `rails db:drop RAILS_ENV=test` and `rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test`) and the tests started behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to pass the user object to the user registration path

```
put user_registration_path(@admin)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd tried that. The route is `user_registration    PUT      /users(.:format)                                                                                  users/registrations#update` and there's no `:id` there. If I add the `(@admin)` then I just get a 'Wrong format' error (because it interprets the user id as a format).

Comment: So how does it know which user you are trying to update?

Comment: This endpoint can only be used to update the current user, so it's not needed - that's how Devise is set up.

Comment: OK, I've never used Devise, but "user_registration_path" sounds like it's for creating new users, not updating existing ones.

Comment: No, that's `new_user_registration_path`, I'm afraid, and they're automatically created by Devise.

Comment: so why does the form code that you've put in the question pass the user object to the path generating method? `form_for(@user, url: registration_path(@user), ...)`

Comment: Rails... It turns `registration_path(@user)` into `user_registration_path` (effectively). This is just how Rails and Devise are. As I said, I tried what you suggested (before I posted my question, in fact) and it didn't help. I'll post my routes in the question, so you can see what's there.